# Spring Batch - Write multiple files based on records count

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In spring batch, I have an requirement to read from the database and to write in a file, The no of rows allowed in a file is N, so if N+10 records are fetched then two files should be created containing N rows and 10 rows respectively.

Can someone please help me with the writer implementation? Is there any other easy way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: Currently am trying in a separate tasklet by passing the object list and traversing the list and creating files. I want to know how to achieve this through spring writer itself..

Comment: [MultiResourceItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemWriter.html)

Comment: Thanks  Luca Basso Ricci..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring batch has `MultiResourceItemWriter` were you can write based on number of lines

```
<bean id="multiWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemWriter">
        <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemWriter" />
        <property name="itemCountLimitPerResource" value="3" />
        <property name="resource" value="file:c:/logs/te" />
</bean>
```

Comment: For each file? The files generated in the above case would be te.1, te.2 etc. you can pass the file name as argument for spring properties or from SB Jobparameter,  <property name="resource" value="file:${filelocation}" />