# Spring Batch - FlatFileItemWriter write to a file, close it, write to new file

Tags: java, spring-batch

So I have a custom class that extends FlatFileItemWriter that I am using to write a CSV file. Based on some condition I want to finish with my first file and then write to a new file. Is there a way to do this with FlatFileItemWriter?

Here is an example of my code:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends MyObject> items) throws Exception {
    ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
    int currentFileIncrememnt = (int) stepContext.get("currentFileIncrement");
    if(currentFileIncrement== fileIncrement) {
        super.write(items);
    }
    else {
        super.close();
        fileIncrement = currentFileIncrement;
        super.setHeaderCallback(determineHeaderCallback());
        super.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/" + fileIncrement+ ".csv"));
        super.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
        DelimitedLineAggregator<MyObject> delLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        delLineAgg.setDelimiter(",");
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyObject> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"id", "amount"});
        delLineAgg.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        super.setLineAggregator(delLineAgg);
        super.write(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hope this gives some insight http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092149/spring-batch-write-multiple-files-based-on-records-count

Answer (score 1):

I don t understand if you are using a custom writer or the spring one. If your using the custom (maybe extendig from spring one) you could use whatever you want by passing parameters through the processor, reader o mapper. If you want to use the Spring writer you should make isolated steps.
Give more details.

Comment: My bad, yes I am extending the FlatFileItemWriter. I will add some details

Comment: I think you tried the solution in that code. Does it work? Post the exception or behaviour. Anyways i think it is a better idea to have different batch steps and using the same writer. If you decide to do this, you have to put your control code in the reader or processor.